# Firebase Firestore OrderBy does not work when used with multiple where conditions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get an ordered set of results based on the `messageUpdatedAt` field(Timestamp).


Tried the below code.

```
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('conversations')
      .where('type', '==', 'direct')
      .where('ids', 'array-contains', id)
      .orderBy('messageUpdatedAt', 'DESC')
      .limit(limit)
```

If i run this, I get an unordered result set. But if I comment the arrary-contains `where` condition(`where('ids', 'array-contains', id)`), the results are ordered(based on the `messageUpdatedAt` field). 
Added below composite index to collection `conversation`.

```
type - Ascending
ids - Array
messageUpdatedAt - Descending
```

Am i doing something wrong ? Is there anyway run this without commenting and get an ordered result set (based on `messageUpdatedAt` field).

Comment: Range filters can be apploed on only one field. you cannot use 2 fields.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries

Comment: also see if you can put the value id inside single quotes.

Comment: @yoga as per the docs, the equality operator is not listed as a range operator. Value of `id` is a string.

Comment: @yoga Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: did putting the single quotes helped?

Comment: change it to something like this         .where('ids', '==', 'id')

Comment: I am facing the same issue where the combination of 'array-contains' and 'orderBy' does not seem to work well. I get the data as soon as I remove the orderBy condition. Indexes are set so wonder what the issue is. Did you find any way to get this working?

Comment: @LMGagne For me orderBy field for some documents were `undefined`. That prevented the ordering of documents. Try to log the data of the field for which you wish to order the documents and check whether any data is something else. Update those document by giving some default value (unix epoch time in my case). This should give you the documents in order.

Answer (score 0):

For me, orderBy field for some documents was `undefined` and some documents didn't have that field. That prevented the ordering of documents. I updated those fields by giving a default value (Unix epoch time) and got the documents in order.